# FCPX => DaVinci Resolve => FCPX color grading round trip

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, color-correction

I'm trying to get my (non-graded) video from Final Cut Pro X through DaVinci Resolve 10.1 Lite, and back into FCPX for the last bits (audio, logos etc). The first part wasn't that hard, just export the FCPX project as XML, and load that from DaVinci Resolve. The color grading itself was a bit harder but still very doable.

The hardest part is getting the graded clips from DaVinci Resolve back into FCPX. I went to the **Deliver** page, set the **Easy setup** to *Final Cut Pro XML Round-Trip*, selected all the clips and selected a destination. After adding the job and running the job, I looked in the directory that was just created and saw a bunch of videos there and a *fcpxml* file. But importing that *fcpxml* file into FCPX just loads the clips from their original location...

So, how is this round trip supposed to work between Final Cut Pro X and DaVinci Resolve Lite?

I've spend the better part of today trying to figure that out, but all I can find are YouTube clips explaining how to do it with Premiere Pro or other video editors. And when I do manage to find something about Final Cut Pro X, it says I should just go to **File**=>**Export AAF, XML**. Unfortunately that option is greyed out for me. And all the other docs are either refering to Resolve 8 or 9. Even the official documentation still refers to a **Conform** page which is long gone in Resolve 10, and replaced by the **Color** page. Too bad I can't find a way to export from there either :(

Comment: A kludgy workaround would be to open the XML file in a text editor and do a find-n-replace on the file path of the original clips, replacing it with the path to the graded clips. Eg if your ungraded clips are like /mediaDrive/rushes/clip1.mov and your graded clips are like /MediaDrive2/graded_clips/clip1.mov, replace mediaDrive/rushes with MediaDrive2/graded_clips, save (as a copy, need I say) and import into FCPX.

Comment: Apparently, the real "solution" to this would be to import all the media into Resolve from the get go and optionally do some initial grading. Then export that stuff to Final Cut Pro for editing, then back to Resolve for final grading and after that's done it can be exported. That can be the end of the line (if done through Resolve) or you can go back to FCPX again and do some final stuff.

Comment: makes sense. I've been introduced to DaVinci since getting a BMCC and to edit the footage you need to do a one-light grade before going to FCP.

Comment: I am used to import from HDV into FCPX and edit it there. So guess I'll redo the color grading from this in FCPX. Good lesson for the next time. Luckily this was just a personal project...

Comment: Are the video files that accompany the fcpxml file the original clips or the graded clips?  Is it possible to post the XML file somewhere?  It sounds almost like FCPX might not be able to find the new files or something, but I'm only able to guess since I have neither a Mac, nor FCPX, nor a setup that can run Resolve, even on Windows.

Comment: The files linked in the FCPXML are the original clips, and yes I could edit the FCPXML file. But I'm not bored enough to go and edit the shit. Maybe I should though, but a bit more experience with the FCPX included color grading would be nice too :) If you want to look at the XML, I uploaded it @ http://pastebin.com/g2tc2xr9

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I've got nothing since the XMl itself is still referring to the original paths.  Clearly you need some other kind of export from Resolve, but I don't know enough about Resolve to be of any help there sadly.  Good luck.

Comment: Did you render with unique file names in Resolve?  It's also important to be careful if you are using the XML Round Trip settings or the Export to FCP settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xudonax,

The preset Final Cut Pro XML Round-Trip renders the graded files in ProRes 422, but it uses an old XML file, not supported in FCPX. You need to go to the Edit (important!) section of DaVinci after rendering the project. Then you will be need to make File – Export AAF, XML... command and check the fcpxml version 1.3 type of file. It will be comfortable to save this five in the same folder used for rendered files in Deliver section.

After that you can do simple import of this FCPXML file in Final Cut Pro X, it will create new Event and Project in your current library with all your graded files.

Be sure to make render before XML-export. If you will export FCPXML ver. 1.3 without delivering, you will make the FCPX-project with original (non-graded) files.
Good luck!

Comment: I have another big event coming up, so I'll try this in a few days. Thanks!

Comment: This works great! Thank you soo much! Now I can finally start doing some real color grading. ~100 hours of footage to go, so that should be enough to get a basic grip on it ;)